# adding a "success message" in .PHP

Tags: php, jquery, html, forms

I'm trying to add a message showing up after the mail has sent saying the message was successfully dispatched but I do not know how to insert it in the PHP request part. I pre-baked the html but I cannot link it. Should I involve JQuery?

```
  if ($conn->connect_error) {
        array_push($errors, "We are having problems at the moment. PLease try again later");
    } 

    if (empty($errors)) {
        // prepare mysql query and bind variables
        $query = "INSERT INTO contact_requests (firstname, lastname, email, company, requested_services, `message`) 
                            VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
        if (!$stmt) {
            array_push($errors, "We are having problems at the moment. PLease try again later");
        }
    }

    if (empty($errors)) {
        if(!$stmt->bind_param("ssssss", $name, $last_name, $email, $company, $services, $message)) {
            array_push($errors, "We are having problems at the moment. PLease try again later");
        }
    }

    if (empty($errors)) {
        if(!$stmt->execute()) {
            array_push($errors, "We are having problems at the moment. PLease try again later");
        }
    }
}

function sanitize_input($data)
{
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);

    return $data;
}
```

HTML

```
    <div id="success_message" style="width:100%; height:100%; display:none;">
        <h3>Sent your message successfully!</h3>
    </div>
```

Comment: Your title states you want to do this "in PHP" but your question states "in JQuery" - which is it? You call `if (empty($errors)) {` several times to do different parts of the query, why not have them all in one `if` then an `else` to show the errors (or pass them to the view or whatever)

Comment: Sorry I edited. As you can read now I mean if I should inculde or not JQuery for example adding a function stating that "if" no errors ==> display successful message

Comment: No probs, I already suggested a way to do that :) either an else or simply a separate `if ($errors)`